# center a fixed width div within a percentage width div

Tags: html, css

How do I horizontally center a fixed-width div within a percentage-width div?

For example in this fiddle, I'd like the Google logo centered.

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">Hello</div>
</div>

.box {
border-radius: 4px;
width: 30%;
margin-right: 2%;
margin-top: 10px;
background: #fff;
float: left;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid #bdc9dc;
height: 200px;
}

.box .image {
height: 160px;
width: 400px;
background-color: #ff1769;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FloatLeft/g2u4E/

I've looked at various 'solutions' online and I haven't found anything that worked.

Comment: .box .image {margin:0 auto;}

Comment: Is the image always 400px? You can add `margin-left: -200px;` to `.image`

Comment: Hi David, Yes, that works. Not sure why I missed that. However If you do that in the fiddle you get a white bar to the right of the pink. I wonder why?

Answer (score 1):

you can center the logo easy by setting background image for the div and change the background size as you need :

```
.box .image {
   height: 160px;
   width:400px;
   background-color:#ff1769;
   background-image: url('http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
   background-size:47% 100%;
}
```

see [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g2u4E/4/)

Comment: Hi Moath, That make the logo out of proportion.

Comment: @FloatLeft you can change the background-size ,, and background:position as you  need ..

Comment: moath, that still doesn't centre the div within the other div. for that solution to work I'd have to apply the background to the containing div (.box)

Comment: If you change the width of .box .image to 100% (as David does in his solution) then it works.

Comment: @FloatLeft may be i didn't get your point, but whatever :P
check this funny one http://jsfiddle.net/g2u4E/11/

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
.box .image {
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#ff1769;
    background-position:center center; 
}
```

Add the image as a background image.

http://jsfiddle.net/g2u4E/5/

Comment: Yes, that does work. However, I was hoping to maintain an img tag rather than setting the background image of the div using CSS.

Comment: Not sure why this has been down-voted as it is a viable solution.

Comment: @FloatLeft I do something similar on my website - but the width is constant so I offset it using a negative margin. Not sure if the width of the image is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.box {
border-radius: 4px;
width: 30%;
margin-right: 2%;
margin-top: 10px;
background: #fff;
float: left;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid #bdc9dc;
height: 200px;
}

.box .image {
height: 160px;
width: 400px;
background-color: #ff1769;
margin:auto;
}

.box .image img{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

A div with `fixed` or `%` width can be aligned to center of its parent container by applying

`margin:0 auto;`

For Eg:

```
#divToCenter{
  height: 160px;
  width: 400px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: In your fiddle the parent container has only `width:30%` and your logo seems so bigger. So increase it to 100% and check. So that you can understand the change occurs while adding `margin:0 auto`

Comment: dont know why downvoted. Its bcos he used a logo bigger than his parent container.

Comment: I assume its because he didn't want to change the parent div width as he question says he wants to center it within the div with the width set to 30%.

Comment: because it doesn't answer his question

Comment: @DavidNguyen His question is **Centre a fixed width div within a percentage width div**.. rite?? and i have already written a comment saying the detail.

Comment: Open the fiddle, enter your code. It doesn't work hence it doesn't answer his question.

Comment: @FloatLeft Then please change your question to an apt one like **Center an image inside a div with % width** or something. Your question says **center a fixed width div within a percentage width div**.

Comment: Prasanth, my question stands but perhaps the question title should have been "Centre a fixed width div within a percentage width div where the container div is smaller than the contained div". Your method of auto margins is fine when the containing div is bigger than the contained div but not when containing div is smaller. So then  perhaps my title is correct in that I want the contained div centred at all times and not just when the container width is bigger.